# Searching for set cookies in wireshark does not show all the cookies that are set in the browser

Tags: http, cookies, wireshark

I first cleared all the cookies in my browser. Then I went to www.yahoo.com. Mean while wireshark was capturing. In the search field of the wireshark, I entered http.set_cookie. But the filtered packets do not show all the cookies that are set in the browser. For example, the cookies shown(in wireshark) in the domain in.yahoo.com is only fpc. Where as in the browser 6 more cookies are set in that domain(like fpps, fpc_s, fpt etc)
Why is this happening? Is wireshark not able to capture all the packets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I browsed to in.yahoo.com and ran Wireshark while first accessing the site. I was able to see the cookies with the following filter -

http.set_cookie && ip.src eq 98.139.183.24

Wireshark will see any cookies set so I suspect in your case, the web-server didn't send them. It may not have sent them because that element of the page wasn't requested as it was still in the browser cache. Repeat your test ensuring there's nothing in your browser cache.

HTH!